# How to resolve generic interface from class type

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a small problem configuring an Autofac module. I want to resolve a  IValidator (Fluent Validator) service with a command pattern, but I don't know how.

Here are my commands:

```
public interface ICommand

public interface ICreateCommand<TDto> : where TDto is IDto

public CreateUserCommand : ICreateCommand<UserDto>
```

Here's my validator:

```
public CreateCommandValidator<TDto> : AbstractValidator<ICreateCommand<TDto>>
```

I want to get `CreateCommandValidator` when resolving `IValidator<CreateUserCommand>` but I only get a `ComponentNotRegisteredException`.

My autofac config:

```
        var assembly = typeof(CommandModule)
            .GetTypeInfo()
            .Assembly;

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
            .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(ICommandHandler<>))
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.RegisterType<CommandDispatcher>()
            .As<ICommandDispatcher>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        libraryAssembly = typeof(ICommand)
            .GetTypeInfo()
            .Assembly;

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(libraryAssembly)
            .Where(x => x.IsAssignableTo<ICommand>())
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();

    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(libraryAssembly )
        .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IValidator<>))
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Answer (score 0):

Does AbstractValidator inherit IValidator?

Basically i register types like this :

```
var types = assembly.GetTypes().Where( t => t.IsClosedTypeOf( typeof( IValidator<> ) ) );
```

I have fiddle. Maybe you can find solution there https://dotnetfiddle.net/fw4IBw